# Isolating dual voltage DC fan control

Tags: voltage, diodes, dc

I am running electric cooling fans on a vehicle which has both 12 V and 24 V circuits. I would like to have the fans have a low and high speed (12 V and 24 V respectively). Current draw is approximately 11 A on 12 V and 25 A on 24 V. Would this be as simple as a diode on the +12 V wire to prevent +24 V from heading the wrong way, or am I under-thinking this?

Comment: Please add a schematic of what you propose.

Answer (score 1):

A SPDT or DPDT switch if the grounds need to change too would be the easiest way to do this. Make sure the switch is rated for at least 24 DC amps; the AC rating is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be as simple as a diode on the +12v wire to prevent +24v from heading the wrong way, or am I under-thinking this?

Using a diode to achieve dual-speed control might not be the best approach.

> I am running electric cooling fans on a vehicle which has both 12v and 24v circuits. I would like to have the fans have a low and high speed (12v and 24v respectively). AMP draw is approximately 11A on 12V and 25A on 24V.

Let's discuss your setup and then explore the best way to implement it:

When a fan is rated for 12V operation and you apply 24V, it's going to spin much faster, likely beyond its designed limits. This can reduce the life of the fan and cause noise or other issues. However, if your fan is specifically designed to handle both 12V and 24V, then it’s a different story. Your idea is to run the fans at half speed (12V) or full speed (24V).

In a simple setup:

- For 12V operation, you'd supply power from the 12V circuit.
- For 24V operation, you'd supply power from the 24V circuit.

Diodes are one-way devices, allowing current to flow in one direction and blocking it in the opposite direction. You're considering using a diode to prevent 24V from feeding back into the 12V circuit, which is logical.

However, there are other concerns:

- Diodes introduce a voltage drop, usually 0.6 to 0.7V for regular silicon diodes. This will cause some loss in your circuit.
- When using diodes to handle high currents (like 11A or 25A), they need to be appropriately rated and might require heatsinking.

**There is much better approach:**

Using relays can be a more robust solution for this kind of setup. Here's a simple approach:

1. Use a Double Pole, Double Throw (DPDT) relay.
2. Wire the fans through the relay.
3. The relay's common terminal goes to the fans.
4. One set of normally closed contacts connect to your 12V source, and the other set of normally open contacts connect to your 24V source.
5. Use a control switch to energize the relay coil. When the relay is de-energized, the fans get 12V. When the relay is energized, it switches to give the fans 24V.

This approach ensures a clear separation between the 12V and 24V circuits and avoids potential issues with diode voltage drops. Make sure to fuse both the 12V and 24V inputs appropriately for safety.

Answer (score 0):

A 30A - 2P3T rotary selector switch will keep the 12 V & 24 V circuits isolated.

[image]